# CPU usage command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, cpu, cpu-usage

I want to get the cpu usage. I tried this command

```
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1}'
```

Could you confirm if this command is correct?

The OS is ubuntu

Comment: It would help if you added your OS to the question. Please [edit] and do so.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux

Comment: Rather than top, there are tools which might be easier.  Have you considered "vmstat" or "iostat -c"?

Comment: Also note that you cannot get an instantaneous read on CPU use... any tool you use will have to monitor over an interval of time.  Metrics in /proc/stat - which are used by top, iostat, and vmstat (as evidenced by running any of these under strace) - are TOTALS since server boot.  To get use over a one second interval, you would have to poll this "file" twice and compute the difference.